# getUserLoginId() doesn't for collaborators

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

getUserLoginId() works for me, but not my collaborators.  We all have edit permission.  We all have gmail accounts and login as such.  The following function is installed as an onEdit trigger.  What's the problem?  I took a look at this link: [Google script: getUser() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938703/google-script-getuser-not-working) which seems to have a related problem.  In there, they talk about "logging into the api".  So I followed that road.  Seriously?  Authentication to find out who is editing a shared spreadsheet?  If that is in fact the path to salvation, does anyone have the code written to perform such a task?  Or am I doomed to spend another week or more banging my head to find out the name of the collaborator I gave permission to modify my spreadsheet, that is actually modifying my spreadsheet?

```
function happyFunTime() {
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var r = s.getActiveCell();
      var timeLastCalledColumnOffset = getTimeLastCalledColumnOffset();

      timeLastCalledColumnOffset++;

        var dateCell = s.getRange(r.getRow(), timeLastCalledColumnOffset);
        var targetSheetName=setRowColor(i);
        var user=Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
        var comment="Last Edited By: " + user;
        dateCell.setComment(comment);

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session.getActiveUser() only works for users within a particular domain. Or if your script is deployed as a web app and set to execute as the user running the app.

In your case, neither of them is true. So, I'm afraid, you're out of luck.

Comment: Consumer accounts (like you mention) are not Google Apps accounts.  Google cannot determine whether you have any relationship with the other Gmail users.  In the Google Apps sense, they know you all work for the same company.

Comment: How is it that google is unable to determine that I have a relationship with the other gmail users, when the spreadsheet is set to "private"?  Isn't it a pretty good assumption that if this particular set of users all have access to a private spreadsheet that there must be a relationship?